# simple C++ GUI as a XUL replacement?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, user-interface, xul

I have an old program that uses XUL and Mozilla Prism to display a simple GUI.  It's written in c++ and I use Visual Studio 2005.  It's a simple thing which sends recorded data at a certain rate over the internet.  It has a slider bar which shows what timestep the data is at, and if you drag it it lets you set the time to a certain point.  It has radio buttons to set the rate multiplier (1x, 10x, 25x).

Anyway, it looks like they discontinued Mozilla Prism and I'd like to move away from using XUL.  I've found info on windows forms and also wxwidgets.  I don't care if it only runs on Windows.  What's the simplest to implement way to get a basic GUI working with radio buttons and slider bars?

Comment: "What do you guys recommend?" is not really a good fit to the Q&A format of this site. All you're going to get is a bunch of people's opinions with no "correct" or verifiable answers. There are lots of other questions that have already been asked on GUI libraries for C++; use the search feature and pick one you like.

Comment: Okay, I edited the question to be more specific

Comment: Greetings, I know you want to move away from XUL, but XULrunner itself  is still supported ( and will always be), using that with an XPCOM interface should do what you require.

Comment: Ah, I see.  However, Prism still uses the old pre-Firefox 4.0 version of Gecko.  Plus, I'd like to go with something simpler since it's just a simple GUI I need anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple work, embedding TCL/TK is a pretty solid choice.  Once you get beyond simple uses it takes discipline to keep good separation of concerns, though.

Comment: @JoeLyga There may be others worth investigating if you want to stay in pure C++, though I can't offer advice on how easy they are.  I somewhat expected others to have that input.  FLTK, IUP come to mind.